# How to uninstall a gem from a production deployment with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano, bundler, rvm-capistrano

I am deploying a rails app to production so gems go in shared/bundle. The mysql2 gem seems to have an issue in Ubuntu12.04 so I'd like to remove it and reinstall but how would I do this? I can't just call `gem uninstall mysql2`. I tried `bundle exec gem uninstall mysql2 --path shared/bundle` but got the error `Could not locate Gemfile`. How would I remove this? If you need any more info, lmk.

thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be in the directory containing the `Gemfile` (such as your deployed project's `current` directory) in order for `bundle exec` to work. Try `cd /path/to/your/project/current` first, then `bundle exec gem uninstall mysql2`.

If that still does not work, you can always just remove the gem manually. Just go to your bundle directory and `rm -rf` all the files/subdirectories related to that gem.